# Attaching files with Dir getting a "Verify the path and file name are correct" error?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I'm trying to make a loop to send an email to a list of people, with each person receiving their own Excel file. The first part hasn't been set up, so I have placeholder information for who it's going to, but I'm having problems with attachments.

The program works without the attachments line, but when I add that, I get

> Verify the path and file name are correct

```vb
Sub AttachAndEmail()
Dim fileDirectory As String
Dim fileCriteria As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim emailApplication As Object
Dim emailItem As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set emailApplication = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err.Number > 0 Then Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set emailItem = emailApplication.CreateItem(0)
On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

fileDirectory = "C:\Users\DW1085\Downloads\a\"

fileName = Dir(fileDirectory)

Do While Len(fileName) > 0
    
    emailItem.to = "Myname@email.com"
    
    emailItem.Subject = "WowweWow"
    
    emailItem.Body = "Yup"

    emailItem.Attachments.Add fileName
    
    emailItem.Display

    fileName = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you giving the path to a file or a directory?

Comment: When you use `Dir` you strip the path out and are left with a filename. You need the full path. And you probably need a wildcard as well (?).

Comment: Did you try stepping thru your code as it runs so you can check the variables? That's always a good place to start when troubleshooting.

Comment: `emailItem.Attachments.Add fileDirectory & fileName`

Comment: I did check to see how it ran without the attachments line, and it seemed to run just as intended. I'm pretty new to using VBA, so I wasn't aware about Dir doing that, so that one is good to know. I'll try what you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. So, you need to pass a full path to the file you want to be attached. For example:

```
Sub AddAttachment() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myAttachments = myItem.Attachments 
 myAttachments.Add "C:\Test.doc", olByValue, 1, "Test" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```